# scrapy custom output processor

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using the scrapy framework for a web scraping project but I can't seem to figure out how to get a custom output processor to work.

I have an item class like so:

```
class Item(scrapy.Item)

    ad_type = scrapy.Field()
```

then my parse function looks something like this. I have 2 scraped strings which I am adding to the ad_type. I want my output processor function to assign tags based on what is scraped from these 2 xpaths.

```
def parse(self, response):

    l = ItemLoader(item=Item(), selector=listing)
    l.add_xpath('ad_type', '(.//div/@class)[1]')
    l.add_xpath('ad_type', '(.//div[contains(@class, "brand")]/@class)[1]')
    yield l.load_item()
```

How do I get my output processor function to access the 2 xpath scraped strings that I have added to ad_type? The scrapy docs give this example but I can't get it to work.

```
def lowercase_processor(self, values):
    for v in values:
        yield v.lower()

class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    name_in = lowercase_processor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named your loader `MyItemLoader`, but your spider uses `ItemLoader` (probably scrapy's).
If you update your code to use the custom loader, you should get the result you want.

I would also recommend not naming your item class `Item`, since that could be confusing.